# Sending mails with embedded logo in Javamail

Tags: java, outlook, jakarta-mail, html-email, attachment

I have a program which sends emails to user in Javamail and I had to embed a logo to every mail. This is working perfect, but in Outlook I see the icon as an attachment to the mail. Logo is displayed in right place along with the html message. But I dont want to see the attachment icon. When I send the same mail to a Gmail account, it looks perfect, I see the logo in right place and no attachment icon. Below is my code:

```
 String htmlText = "<H1>Hello</H1><img src=\"cid:image\">";
 messageBodyPart.setContent(htmlText, "text/html");

 //Create a multipart message
 Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");

 //Set text message part
 multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

 //Part two is attachment
 messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
 URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource("testgif.gif");
 DataSource source = new URLDataSource(url);
 messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
 messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<image>");
 messageBodyPart.setDisposition(MimeMessage.INLINE);
 multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

 message.setContent(multipart);

 Transport.send(message);
```

Comment: I guess Outlook always shows images like attachments. I've done a quick peek to my outlook messages and every email with logos, signatures, etc, show as attachments.

Comment: The previous implementation in my proj doesnot show the attachment icon though the logo is displayed.  I dont see any significant difference between my implementation from the original one. Not sure what is causing to display the attachment icon.  If i remove the line messageBodyPart.setDisposition(MimeMessage.INLINE); gmail also shows the attachment icon and logo is  displayed inline.

Comment: I sent a sample mail from outlook, i just copy pasted the same logo and i dont see attachment icon to that mail.

Comment: Now I am more confused..I dont see the icon now.  I swear its same code :) .. Can some one please help me understanding this..When it will show the attachment icon and when it will not???

Comment: I resolved this using ByteArrayDataSource..                                  MimeBodyPart imagePart = new MimeBodyPart();
DataSource fds = new ByteArrayDataSource(imageBytes, imageType);
imagePart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));                       thank you

Comment: Glad it's already solved. Could you please post as valid answer? thanks.